# Wildcard alias for Elastic index

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-indices

I've got an Elastic index `transactions-internal` and would like to point all the names like `transactions-([a-z]+)-internal` to this index using alias, so all the requests like

```
GET /transactions-a-internal/_search
GET /transactions-b-internal/_search
GET /transactions-c-internal/_search
...
etc
```

should give the same result as

```
GET /transactions-internal/_search
```

I've tried

```
POST /transactions-internal/_alias/transactions-*-internal
```

but it returned

```
Invalid alias name [...] must not contain the following characters [ , \", *, \\, <, |, ,, >, /, ?]
```

Is there any "smart" solution for that? **I would strongly prefer co configure it on Elastic side, not anywhere else.**

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. It's the [other way around](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-add-alias.html), i.e. `POST /<index>/_alias/<alias>`

```
POST /transactions-*-internal/_alias/transactions-internal
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want the [other way around](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html), then you can use the following (note that an alias name cannot contain wildcard characters):

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        { "add" : { "index" : "transactions-internal", "alias" : "transactions-a-internal" } },
        { "add" : { "index" : "transactions-internal", "alias" : "transactions-b-internal" } },
        { "add" : { "index" : "transactions-internal", "alias" : "transactions-c-internal" } }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `no such index [...] transactions-*-internal`, as I said: the only index I have currently is `transactions-internal` but I'd like to have it accessible under different names

Comment: Thanks @Val, upvoted, but not marked as resolved - the whole point was to have it configured dynamically, without specifying all the names. Probably I'm gonna need some HTTP proxy for that if it's not possible inside Elastic itself.

Comment: I'm curious, may I ask you to explain your use case in a bit more details? There might be other ways to solve your problem.

Comment: We maintain third-party enterprise application which is expecting separate index for every introduced datasoruce (even datasources which we don't need on some environments). No full access to the source code = no other way to solve the problem I guess :)

Comment: Have you tried investigating [filtered aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#filtered), that can give the illusion of separate indices, yet you only need to manage a single one.

Comment: @Val sir, can you pls show some path regarding this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60923264/elasticsearch-add-password-to-only-delete-index-api

Comment: with filtered aliases we still need to add every single alias manually so I guess it's not an answer

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this is applicable to your situation but if you're starting from scratch a possible solution might be to use a index template.

```
PUT _index_template/transactions-internal
{
  "priority": 1,
  "template": {
    "aliases": {
      "transactions-internal": {}
    }
  },
  "index_patterns": [
    "transactions-*-internal"
  ],
  "composed_of": []
}
```

As I'm quite new to elastic I don't know if this template can be applied to an existing index.But this approach will work for new indizes in v 7.12.1